# mysql_fetch_assoc data to COOKIE in user browser

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I had data in mysql, where it does not need any security.

I had a sql query string to get the data out every time using mysql_fetch_assoc.

So, I planed to store data in users browser.To reduce no of quires to sql.

```
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['countries'])){
    $query = "SELECT iso,name FROM sel_country";
    $countries = mysql_query($query);
    setcookie('countries', serialize($countries), time()+3600);
   }else{
    $countries = $unserialize($_COOKIE['countries']);
    }
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($countries)) {echo $row['name']}
```

But, When cookie is set it is showing following error

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/worlds/public_html/index/ctrl.php on line 15

My cookie in browser displaying content as i%3A0%3B

Please help me out, how should i go?

Comment: You can't serialize a result resource, you need to use mysql_fetch_assoc on it first. The results haven't actually been pulled from the mysql server until you call the fetch method.

Comment: but,if we do so, we will get only 1 row  as array .but other rows will be lost

Comment: I mean of course to loop like you do on the bottom of your script, just store that and serialize the stored array. See my answer for an example.

Comment: ok you mean loop in to multi-dimensional array ? if so,way we output will also change.so we need to add few lines.Very good idea. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serialize a result resource, you need to use mysql_fetch_assoc on it first. The results haven't actually been pulled from the mysql server until you call the fetch method.

Like this:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['countries'])){
    $query = "SELECT iso,name FROM sel_country";
    $countries = mysql_query($query);
    $result = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($countries)) {$result[] = $row['name']}
    setcookie('countries', json_encode($result), time()+3600);

    //And to make the rest of the script able to use it as below:
    $countries = $result;
} else {
    $countries = json_decode($_COOKIE['countries']);
}
```

Comment: @GowthamRaj If this answer was the answer to your question, consider marking it as "Accepted" by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: when i am setting: setcookie('countries', serialize($result), time()+3600); i am getting 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @GowthamRaj Actually, deserializing a cookie is a security flaw (just did some research), use json_encode/json_decode instead (see my edit).

Comment: @GowthamRaj Also keep in mind that the list of countries in the cookie can be **edited** by users, so make sure it's not used for anything vital.

Comment: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/adstrsli/public_html/pages/initate.php:15) in /home/adstrsli/public_html/pages/initate.php on line 16

Comment: No because i am verifying country received from cookie = session set

Comment: Yes but,i have changed method so that if once country get selected then webpage will not ask again.

Answer (score 0):

use unserialise() instead of $unserialize()